# Can you execute multiple statements in an "if" statement?

Tags: lisp

This is my function:

```
(defun MyFunction(input)
  (let ((NEWNUM (find input num)))
    (if (find input num)              //if this 
      (setq num NEWNUM) (FUNCT2)      //then execute both of these
    (list 'not found))))              //else output this
```

So after the `if` statement I want to be able to execute `(setq num NEWNUM)` followed by `(FUNCT2)` in order to set a new variable and then call a function.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Slight offtopic: it seems that the 'num' variable is a special/dynamic (i.e., global) variable. Most probably you don't need one.

Comment: Which Lisp dialect is this code written in?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To do several things in sequence, you want `progn`.

```
(defun MyFunction(input)
  (let ((NEWNUM (find input num)))
    (if (find input num)              //if this 
      (progn 
        (setq num NEWNUM)
        (FUNCT2))      //then execute both of these
    (list 'not found))))              //else output this
```

Comment: Instead of `progn` you can also use `prog1`, which will return value of first expression.

Comment: similar to the usage of `begin` in scheme

Answer (score 13):

When your `if` is 'one-armed', as they call it (that is, it contains no `else` branch), it's typically easier and more idiomatic to use `when` and `unless`: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/hyperspec/HyperSpec/Body/mac_whencm_unless.html

When you call `(when pred x y ... z)`, it will just evaluate `x y z` sequentially if `pred` is true. `unless` behaves similarly when `pred` is NIL. `x y z` can represent any number of statements from one upwards. Thus:

```
(when pred (thunk))
```

is just the same as

```
(if pred (thunk))
```

Some people say `when` and `unless` should always be used for 'one-armed-ifs' because of clarity.

Edit: Your thread gave me an idea. This macro:

```
(defmacro if/seq (cond then else)
  `(if ,cond (progn ,@then) (progn ,@else)))
```

should enable this:

```
(if/seq (find input num)              //if this 
      ((setq num NEWNUM) (FUNCT2))      //then execute both of these
    ((list 'not found)))))
```

So the general format is:

```
(if/seq *condition* (x y ... z) (a b ... c))
```

Depending on the condition, it evaluates all of the subforms in the first or second, but only returns the last.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use multiple statements with `if`, except with `progn` as posted above.  But there is the `cond` form,

```
(cond
 ((find input num)     // if this 
  (setq num NEWNUM)    // then execute both of these
  (FUNCT2))

 (t
  (list 'not found)))  // else output this
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, you could also use the (begin exp1 exp2...) syntax to evaluate more than one expression in Lisp sequentially. Using this on an if's branch will have the same effect as using multiple statements.

Comment: `begin` I think it's only in scheme and he have common lisp code so he need to use `progn` or `prog1`

Comment: I confirm, doesn't work in common lisp