# Recursive function in lisp goes wrong

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a simple recursive program that prints the squares of numbers within certain bounds:

```
(defun show-squares (i end)
    (if (> i end)
        'done
        (format t "~A   ~A~%" i (* i i))
        (show-squares (+ i 1) end)))
```

I get the error: `*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable SHOW-SQUARES has no value`
What goes wrong here?

Comment: `if` only takes three arguments:  the test, the then-part, and the else-part.  You've given it four.

Comment: Also see [Can you execute multiple statements in with a If statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2852249/1281433) and [Consecutive calls/evaluations in a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2878240/1281433)

Comment: judging by the error: functions are values, same as any others, and it seems that your lisp doesn't know what SHOW-SQUARES is; i think you may have forgotten to interpret/compile the code before calling the function.

Comment: @miercoledi That's not the problem here, but it is actually kind of interesting that the error message is so uninformative.  It could be a good exercise to determine why this particular error message occurred.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's what I was thinking; Unless #'if was redefined somewhere in a rather wacky manner, then this error is not the one that should be expected based on a "missing progn" (which I quote because it is a silly diagnosis; the syntax is just wrong all over & pushing a progn takes too many assumptions on the part of the responder to the OP) or unacceptable number of arguments for a form undergoing evaluation.  And let's go ahead and feel safe assuming that #'if wasn't redefined :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect part of the problem is the badly formed if statement.

"if" takes 2 or 3 arguments, and you're passing 4.

Answer (score 3):

You probably missed some `progn` :

```
(defun show-squares (i end)
    (if (> i end)
        'done
        (progn 
            (format t "~A   ~A~%" i (* i i))
            (show-squares (+ i 1) end))))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to rewrite the program without a `progn`. This is actually an example from Paul Graham's Ansi Common Lisp. The problem was with the way I had structured the parentheses. `If` had received 4 arguments. It now works fine: `(format t "~A ~A~%" i (* i i) (show-squares (+ i 1) end))))`